# How to delete a view component on click using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen code like this (Shows a simple list).

What I'm seeking, is to delete the item when it was clicked.

How can I achieve this?

```
HorizontalScroller {
    Row(modifier = Spacing(bottom = 16.dp, right = 16.dp)) {
        posts.forEach { post ->
            WidthSpacer(16.dp)
            Clickable(onClick = {
               // Delete the PostCardPopular I just added if it was clicked
            }) {
               PostCardPopular(post)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this using a model Object and ModelList

```
@Model
object YourModel {
  val posts = ModelList<Post>()
}

.
.
.

HorizontalScroller {
    Row(modifier = Spacing(bottom = 16.dp, right = 16.dp)) {
        for(post in YourModel.posts)
            WidthSpacer(16.dp)
            Clickable(onClick = {
               YourModel.posts.remove(post)
            }) {
               PostCardPopular(post)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

When you remove from ModelList, the UI will recompose.

Extra: Google releases a codelab for basic compose. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics/